# argument unused during compilation: '-unwindlib=libunwind'

Tags: c++, linker, clang, llvm, clang++

I installed LLVM 17 on MacOS and set the following environment variables to use it instead of the native Apple Clang:

```
PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -fuse-ld=lld -rtlib=compiler-rt -unwindlib=libunwind -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++"
CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"
```

When I configure a CMake project, `build.ninja` contains aomething like this for each target:

```
# Link the executable <...>
  FLAGS = -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk
  LINK_FLAGS = -L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -fuse-ld=lld -rtlib=compiler-rt -unwindlib=libunwind -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++
```

And the corresponding `rules.ninja`:

```
# Rule for linking CXX executable.
rule CXX_EXECUTABLE_LINKER__<...>
  command = $PRE_LINK && /opt/homebrew/opt/ccache/libexec/clang++ $FLAGS -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names $LINK_FLAGS $in -o $TARGET_FILE $LINK_PATH $LINK_LIBRARIES && $POST_BUILD
  description = Linking CXX executable $TARGET_FILE
  restat = $RESTAT
```

When I build the project, Clang complains:

```
[61/395  12% :: 11.894] Linking CXX executable <...>
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-unwindlib=libunwind' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

I am pretty sure that this argument is passed during linking, not compilation, so what's going on?

Comment: What happens if you change that into two dashes instead of just one?

Comment: Per [documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/17.0.1/tools/clang/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-unwindlib) (emphasis mine): `-unwindlib=<arg>`, `--unwindlib=<arg>`

Unwind library to use. `<arg>` **must be** `‘libgcc’`, `‘unwindlib’` or `‘platform’`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, no change

Comment: @Yksisarvinen , This must be a typo.  Looking in the source: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Allvm%2Fllvm-project+unwindlib&type=code vs https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Allvm%2Fllvm-project+libunwind&type=code

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, typo has been fixed in later version: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html

Comment: @AlexO I don't see any typo fixed? It still says it should be `-unwindlib=unwindlib`, not `-unwindlib=libunwind`

Comment: You're right, they didn't, but I trust the source more than I trust the documentation :)